# Video not showing

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I add video files to the video editor,  Both audio and video channels appear but only the audio plays.  The video is just a white box.  Anyone know what is wrong.  Added video in WMV.  Also tried MP4 same thing.

Comment: some people have attributed this to outdated video card drivers, or blender versions  in the past, can you give any more information? This seems to happen only in a rare number of cases, therefore the solution is not very well defined.

Comment: I have the latest blender version.  I watched several online tutorials on how to add video and I am following all the steps as far as I can see.  Not sure what else I can provide.

Comment: Hey @Matt, how large is the video, let me try on my end.

Comment: All I want to do is blur out a license plate in a video.  Haha.  All this just for that.  I tried "Wax" video editor but of course when i go to apply the blur effect an error pops up.  Cant win.

Comment: 178mb is the video size

Comment: I'm not sure, never experienced this issue before. Try a build from builder.blender.org or graphicall.org or on another os if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

I already had a graphics cards driver problem with Blender. The developers helped me [out](https://developer.blender.org/T45270#319163) to find out whether the problem is one with the driver.

You should use the opengl32.dll from http://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/ and place it next to `blender.exe` as described by sergey to find out if the problem is your driver. Beware, that Blender might be very slow while using this wrapper dll as everything is done on CPU only without using your graphics card.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46769/2843