# Blender 2.77 - glass shader looks like glossy shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

*I downloaded Blender v2.77 and try to render Suzanne with HDRI Lighting.*

First I've used a glossy shader, then a glass shader and it surprises me that the glass shader totally looks like glossy, it's not glass. When I switch back to Blender v2.76b and render the same file again, everything goes fine, glass is glass and glossy is glossy. See the images and the test file below.

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41146

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gdax.png. It does look like a bug.

Comment: in the future please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload your file. Links to Pasteall.org diappear after a few weeks and then your post will not be complete.

Comment: Same here, I'm glad I'm not alone :). I've got a Sapphire R9 390 NITRO 8 MB ram, 2.76b works perfectly (CPU, GPU supp and exp), 2.77 has that glass/glossy bug only with GPU. I'm going to try various Crimson driver versions, from 15.12 to the latest (16.3.2).

Comment: Does it look like that in the preview rollout panel too?

Comment: If it works on the AMD card in 2.76 and not 2.77, then this is definitely a regression which should be reported

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46769/2843

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/T47668

Answer (score 1):

I cannot confirm this. Glass looks totally normal in 2.77, GPU and CPU.

Some things to check for you:

- Do you use a 2.77 release, not a beta or rc version?
- Do you maybe use *Feature set: Experimental*?
- If it's on GPU, got all the latest drivers?

[image]

Comment: I use AMD Radeon HD 7770 GPU, update latest driver, i download the newest blender 2.77 release, not RC, even the msi set up and the zip file, and it's still not work for me, but when i try the same file with Nvidia GTX GPU, every thing goes fine, may be AMD Graphic Card is not fully support yet, i'll find other way to make glass.

Comment: Well yeah, you should have mentioned the Radeon card. AFAIK Radeon is still experimental. Does it render correctly when you use the Radeon card, but render on CPU? Good luck!