# GPU rendering causes glass to become extreamly reflective

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, gpu

Does anyone know how to get glass to be transparent. I'm using GPU render to render a bowl and cloth but the GPU and CPU final render have different results on the glass bowl

The top image is using the CPU to render

[image]

[image]

the bottom one is the GPU.

Does anyone know why this happens and how i can fix it or work around it?

thanks for any help :)

Comment: My guess is that you are using an AMD card... possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49194/blender-2-77-glass-shader-looks-like-glossy-shader/49202#49202

Comment: @cegaton yeah, im using an AMD card :/ thanks for the help. any suggestions on making glass without using the glass shader?

Comment: Use CPU rendering...

Comment: @cegaton :( I guess till there is an update to fix it i'll have to. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this issue and you are using an AMD graphics card, you can either use CPU rendering or try and fake a glass texture.

I've found that using glossy shader and transparent shader lookes pretty good:
It takes a little longer to render but i think it looks better than the glass shader.[image]

Comment: The issue with that approach is that the refraction is incorrect.

Comment: i know but its better than just using CPU rendering for me at least