# Blender 2.77 crashes on startup, graphic problem

Tags: python, command-line, windows

I have a problem with Blender 2.77.

It crashes on startup with no error message.
I found this problem of graphic settings but I don't really know how to fix this.
Something with my CPU maybe? Got the good drivers I think.

I installed Blender with the installer first (same crash) and now i got the ZIP version.

I got a MSI with: Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit / CPU: i7-4810MQ / GPU: GTx870M

[image]

If you guys can help me, it would be awsome! Thanks.

Comment: Try the new 2.77a - maybe it's already fixed? Else this is a bug which should be reported and not asked here...

Comment: Maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46769/2843