# When dragging to re-parent in the Outliner, I'm not getting any visual feedback. How do I fix this?

Tags: parent, outliner

[image]

In a video I just watched it looks like this:
[image]

But I never got this "Drop to Set Parent" overlay or anything like it.

I'm on 2.77a on Windows 10. Also never got this on 2.77.
What's wrong here and how do I fix it?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: I've never used that for parenting before. I suggest going to 3D view and hitting CTRL + P on the objects you wish to parent. Last object you select is the parent. EDIT: Both of these methods should be identical.

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't answer my question. I'm aware of the CTRL+P parenting but I'd like to know how to fix the display bug that happens when dragging items in the Outliner.

I've since found out that it's caused by the **Window Draw Method** in the **User Preferences > System** menu. When this is set to "Full", the overlay isn't drawn.

Comment: This works without notification *Drop To Set Parent* if using *Full* or *Overlap Flip* draw methods (but parenting will be performed); this works just fine with showing notification *Drop To Set Parent* with any other drawing method, i.e. *Automatic, Triple Buffer, Overlap*. 2.77.

Comment: This might be a bug that you should report. It might as well be just a problem with your [graphics driver](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46769/2843).

Comment: Works on 2.77a for me, so now i can suggest is reinstalling it and then checking drivers, still not fixing it, try resetting to default settings, you may of changed something, If all else fails i suppose it's a bug. Oh, and don't take restore to factory settings lightly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the **Window Draw Method** in the **User Preferences > System** menu. When this is set to "Full", the overlay isn't drawn. Changing it for example to "Overlap" fixes the issue. (however, there are other problems that arise in other parts of Blender when Window Draw Method is not set to "Full")