# Blender 2.79B won't open

Tags: workflow, video, audio, installation

I am getting this "AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead" when I'm trying to open blender now. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error AL lib: UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead. What can I do?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77857/error-al-lib-updatedeviceparams-failed-to-set-44100hz-got-48000hz-instead-wh)

Answer (score 0):

Added this dll to the directory with the opengl32.dll and it's working again.

https://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/win64/

Comment: This is only half of the story. Try updating your drivers and remove the dll. Otherwise this will make blender really slow. see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46766

Comment: you're right it's so slow! I did update the driver and removed the file but it won't open again.